# Replicate look through camera (0) in my app

Tags: 3d-view

I want to replicate the effect of looking through the render camera in my app, but I am not sure how to obtain the 4 points for making the "darkening" effect of the things that are outside the frustum of the render camera.

Given a camera with a width and a height positioned somewhere in space with a projection matrix, and another camera (edit_camera) which I use to navigate my scene, how can I obtain the for points that define the render camera near plane in the edit_camera space?

[image]
[image]

I know this is not exactly a blender question, but Im not sure where to look for this...

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're trying to get. To calculate the red points all you need is camera translation (location, rotation), and its aspect ratio, Based on these you can calculate the plane. If you use blender, you can put a real plane, parented to the camera, (or even better four empties) and capture their locations.

Comment: I want to replicate the way blender shows what the camera sees (as shown in the first picture) in my own tools. For doing that, I think I just need the red points, but its not clear to me how to obtain them. I have location, rotation and aspect ratio of my own camera in my tool, but still, not able to compute the red dots position... basically, I dont know how to compute how far those points are from the camera position and the width and height of the rectangle they create

Comment: say, your canera is z axis pointing to your eye. so, you can abandon z coordinates for now, and deal only x,y. say, your 'sensor' is 16x9, so draw a rectangle (x=16, y=9) around the cam center. (all 4 points are with z coord = 0). Now you can set your z for the rectangle (frustrum focus) as long as you want. then begin to rotate the rectangle with the camera. That's it. you can play with that z offset like with focal length of a real camera with the same effect.

Comment: to get an idea, I'd try to play with camera settings (sensor size, focal length) in blender, looking to camera view, and to camera gizmo with all limits display enabled simultaneously. It can help to understand how real cameras and lenses work.

Comment: But that is not enough for what I want to do. Everythign that is projected onto that rectangle is actually what is going to be rendered, so its not just a matter of moving the rectangle along the Z direction...

Comment: and they are not actually dots. ) they are rays. you just cast those rays from the cam center thru red dots to infinity. so, the dots themselves can be at any (non-zero) distance from center.

Comment: sure, I understand that. The question is, how to find one point on that ray, so I can compute one on each and actually create the rectangle that represents the sensor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108153/discussion-between-mechanic-and-jjcasmar).